# How do I change page title based on heading?

Tags: html

I would like to change the title of my page based on the name of

for example,
`<h1>lorem imsum<h1>` 
would set the page title to `lorem ipsum`

Comment: Please add code you've used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to do it in JS

```
document.title = document.querySelectorAll('h1')[0].textContent
```

Where `[0]` is indicating that you want the text from the first `h1` element. If your `h1` will have an `id` then use that instead as it will explicit therefore safer.

Comment: A more narrow selector would make a lot more sense. This approach breaks as soon as you add another `h1`

Comment: You are right. Hence the indication that using id is better.